# Standard Htaccess directives disappear by themselves

Tags: permalinks, urls, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I have an odd issue on one of my websites.
I'm talking about the standard, native, url directives put by wordpress, that just plain disappear from time to time, which of course breaks my site.

Here is the code :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Les directives (lignes) entre « BEGIN WordPress » et « END WordPress » sont générées
# dynamiquement, et doivent être modifiées uniquement via les filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives situées entre ces marqueurs sera surchargée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've reinstalled WP multiple times, and I don't know what could be causing this.
Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: are you making manual modifications to the lines in-between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`? That entire section is automated and machine generated by WordPress itself, it shouldn't be modified by hand or all your choices are lost everytime WP updates its part of the HTAccess file. Also is that code before or after this happens? What does it look like before/after this? Is it all content or is it modifications that dissapear? Be very very specific ( do not assume people will understand your meaning, you run a high risk of being misunderstood on something you consider obvious )

Comment: I've seen this happen in the past with some plugins that modify the .htaccess file. They somehow strip that part and all but the home page get a blank page as they load. You re-save permalinks and back to normal. Since that re-creates that section. Maybe try with some plugins not enabled?

Comment: @TomJNowell no modifications were made to the htaccess whatsoever. The code shown above is the section that keeps disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a plugin that is affecting your htaccess file. (It shouldn't.)

The htaccess WordPress directives are rewritten when you change the permalinks in Settings. (Which is a good way to get them back if they aren't there.)

I'd do a text search of all plugin's code for 'htaccess'. Once you find the offending plugin, you might consider entering an issue on that plugin's support forum.